# Does Go provide function like memmove in C++

Tags: go, memory

I searched online, and found runtime package has this function but it's unexported.

Does Golang have something like memmove in C++?

`void * memmove ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

I believe [copy](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) is what you are looking for.

```
src := []byte("some data")
dst := make([]byte, len(src))
copy(dst, src)

println(string(dst)) // prints 'some data'
```

Comment: dst and src can be overlapped.
For example:
  char str[] = "1234567890";
  memmove (str+2,str+5,5);
  puts(str);

The output will be: 1267890890

Comment: Right, I don't believe that is supported

Comment: Right. I'll use Cgo instead.

Comment: This is the correct answer, copy's arguments may overlap like with memmove: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy

Answer (score 2):

You can use `go:linkname` compile directive:

```golang
//go:noescape
//go:linkname memmove runtime.memmove
func memmove(to, from unsafe.Pointer, n uintptr)
```

Ref:

https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1649596852-The-magic-of-go%3Alinkname

Answer (score -2):

Finally, I decided to use Cgo. It may lose type safety benefits by calling C. But I can not find any native go code solution.

```
//#include <string.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func Memmove(src, dest unsafe.Pointer, length int) ｛
    C.memmove(dest, src, C.size_t(length))
}
```

Comment: You never did explain what you were trying to do.

Comment: Go's copy supports overlapping arguments, no need for this